# How to access the Azure user information?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

Iam having trouble is accessing the user information of *Azure accounts*, for example i cannot access their email_id, name, pictures etc.. How can i access user information using *Azure Resource Manager (ARM) REST API* set? Briefly i will explain what i have done till now..

**Step 1:** I have registered my application in *Azure Active Directory (AD)* . Then i get my unique tenant id, client id and client key..

**Step 2:** By this i generated access token and i can access my VM's and Azure Resources by *ARM REST API*. But i could not able to find the API to get the user data like their name, pictures and email_id in **ARM REST API** set..

Answer (score 1):

you may use Azure Graph Api for accessing the AD user info.
Use the access token, returned by the Azure AD against which the user is signed-in, for the authentication of REST API.

Use "Azure Graph Explorer" for understanding the graph api.

Comment: Thanks Rahul,
I tried **Azure Graph API** to access the user information using the **API** https://graph.windows.net/{My Tenant_ID}/users?api-version=1.6 and i also added my valid access token in header. But the response was something strange..
_Response:_
`{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
    },
    "values": null
  }
}`

I could not recognize why this response is coming..

Comment: Try this link.
[https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/].

For your use case:
Configure your application in Azure AD to have delegate permissions 
like : Sign-in and read user profile, Sign-in read all user's basic profile.

Store the access token obtained after signing-in successfully with the Azure AD. Use this token and configure http request with valid url for list  of users. 
You would be able to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Hi Rahul Thanks man..
Once I login using graphexplorer.cloudapp.net it is showing below error message, i could not find the exact issue..

Even i tried from 2 different azure account, it is showing the same message.


AADSTS50020: User account 'trov.inc@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'graphExplorerMT' and cannot access the application 'd3ce4cf8-6810-442d-b42e-375e14710095' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account

Comment: graphexplorer.cloudapp.net works only with Azure AD user and not with Microsoft Account user. If, your user is Microsoft Account user, then you have to configure your application's Startup.Auth.cs to get you sign-in with Azure AD integrated WebApp. You need to pass the "Azure AD Domain name" in the Sign-in context. 
I would advice you for using Azure AD user instead.
Use this  [link](https://github.com/dushyantgill/VipSwapper/tree/master/CloudSense)

Answer (score 1):

If you can access VM through accesstoken. I guess your graph api uri has problem. Pls refer to the below format, it is Powershell command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/<tenantid>/users/<userid>?api-version=1.6" -Headers $headers
```